# Проблема с областью видимости переменных

Tags: javascript

Нужно что бы при открытии блока с ответом убиралось подчеркивание нижней границы. Как я понимаю проблема с областью видимости переменных , но как исправить не знаю
Работает только для верхнего блока как нужно

```js
const mainFunction = (e) => {
    const accordions = document.querySelectorAll(".accordion");


    const vault = {
        panel: "accordion__panel",
        button: "accordion__button"
    };

    const classes = {
        activeContent: "accordion__panel-active",
        activeButton: "accordion__button-active"
    };

    const elementButtons = document.querySelectorAll(`.${vault.button}`);
    const elementPanels = document.querySelectorAll(`.${vault.panel}`);

    const accordionEvent = (accordion) => {
        const button = accordion.querySelector(`.${vault.button}`);
        const panel = accordion.querySelector(`.${vault.panel}`);

        const buttonToggleActive = (e) => {
            elementButtons.forEach((n) => {
                n !== button ? n.classList.remove(classes.activeButton) : null;

            });

            button.classList.toggle(classes.activeButton);
        };

        const panelToggleActive = (e) => {
            elementPanels.forEach((n) =>
                n !== panel ? n.classList.remove(classes.activeContent) : null
            );
            panel.classList.toggle(classes.activeContent);
            panel.style.setProperty("--height", `${panel.scrollHeight}px`);
            // эти 2 строчки
            const border = document.querySelector('.accordion__slot');
            border.classList.add('accordion__slot_active');
        };

        button.addEventListener("click", panelToggleActive);
        button.addEventListener("click", buttonToggleActive);
    };

    accordions.forEach((element) => accordionEvent(element));
};

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", mainFunction);
```

```css
  .accordions:first-of-type {
        padding-top: 55px;
    }
    
    .accordions {
        width: 100%;
        width: 743px;
        padding: 0;
    }
    
    .accordion {
        width: 100%;
        height: auto;
    }
    
    .accordion__slot {
        width: 100%;
        display: block;
        border-bottom: 1px solid #D8E3FE;
    }
    
    .accordion__slot_active {
        border-bottom: none;
    }
    
    .accordion__button {
        border-radius: 5px;
        cursor: pointer;
        padding: 27px 20px 25px 55px;
        width: 100%;
        text-align: left;
        border: none;
        outline: none;
        font-size: 15px;
        display: flex;
        justify-content: space-between;
        align-items: center;
        transition: color 500ms ease;
        position: relative;
        /**/
        font-family: Quicksand;
        font-style: normal;
        font-weight: 500;
        font-size: 15px;
        line-height: 19px;
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
        letter-spacing: 0.03em;
        color: #8E96B7;
        background-color: #FFFFFF;
    }
    
    .accordion__button:hover {
        color: #042c73;
    }
    
    .accordion__button::before {
        transition: transform 500ms;
        width: 14px;
        height: 14px;
        display: block;
        position: absolute;
        transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
        top: 37px;
        left: 24px;
        content: "";
        background-position: center;
        background-size: contain;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-image: url(./images/faq-image.svg);
    }
    
    .accordion__button-active::before {
        transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotate(-180deg);
    }
    
    .accordion__button-active {
        color: #760284;
    }
    
    .accordion__panel {
        overflow: hidden;
        max-height: 0;
        visibility: hidden;
        padding: 0 5px;
        transition: visibility 500ms, max-height 600ms;
        transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.694, 0.0482, 0.335, 1);
    }
    
    .accordion__panel-active {
        max-height: var(--height, 0);
        visibility: visible;
    }
    
    .accordion-panel__content {
        padding: 16px 0 52px 80px;
        font-family: Roboto;
        font-style: normal;
        font-weight: normal;
        font-size: 14px;
        line-height: 27px;
        letter-spacing: 0.03em;
        color: #8D96BD;
        margin: 10px 0;
        user-select: none;
        max-width: 400px;
    }
```

```html
 <div class="accordions">
                <div class="accordion">
                    <div class="accordion__slot">
                        <button class="accordion__button">Reque insolens in vel?</button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="accordion__slot">
                        <div class="accordion__panel">
                            <p class="accordion-panel__content">Quidam vocibus eum ne, erat consectetuer voluptatibus ut nam. Eu usu vidit tractatos, vero tractatos ius an, in mel diceret persecuti.</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>
             <div class="accordions">
                <div class="accordion">
                    <div class="accordion__slot">
                        <button class="accordion__button">Reque insolens in vel?</button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="accordion__slot">
                        <div class="accordion__panel">
                            <p class="accordion-panel__content">Quidam vocibus eum ne, erat consectetuer voluptatibus ut nam. Eu usu vidit tractatos, vero tractatos ius an, in mel diceret persecuti.</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Какая необходимость создавать два бордера для одного блока? Вы можете убрать бордер с кнопок

```
<div class="accordion__slot">
  <button class="accordion__button">Reque insolens in vel?</button>
</div>
```

И вам не придется отслеживать события по нажатия кнопки/удаления с нее бордера, просто бордер контента (определенного блока) будет смещаться вниз.

Если хотите все-таки с 2 бордерами. Ваша функция принимает параметр `e - event`

```
const panelToggleActive = (e) => {...}
```

Объект который инициировал событие (то есть кнопка, на которую вы нажали) будет

```
const btn = e.target;
btn.classList.add('accordion__slot_active'); // и уже к инициатору добавляем класс
```

вместо

```
 // эти 2 строчки
 const border = document.querySelector('.accordion__slot');
 border.classList.add('accordion__slot_active');
```

Comment: O_o воистину. Хотя у автора совсем другая ошибка) querySelector берет первый подходящий элемент, а надо как-то узнать, на какой по счету элемент кликнули. И взять его через querySelectorAll.

Comment: @OPTIMUSPRIME  а если я прописываю querySelectorAll то все равно берет 1ый

Comment: @gluschk0v.valery, вы ищите сложные пути. Добавляйте класс  посредством `e`, у вас же `const panelToggleActive = (e)`

Comment: `e`  - элемент на котором произошло событие. А так `const border = document.querySelector('.accordion__slot');          border.classList.add('accordion__slot_active');` вы каждый раз добавляете только к первому эл-ту класс

Comment: @azlov сейчас попробую разобраться

Comment: @azlov Если все правильно понял , то выношу в отдельную функцию и через е добавляю ?

Comment: @gluschk0v.valery, обновил ответ

Comment: @azlov благодарю

Comment: @azlov я только не понял про 2 бордера на кнопке же есть border:none;

Comment: @gluschk0v.valery, у вас один бордер на `div` (в котором лежит кнопка) `<div class="accordion__slot"><button class="accordion__button">Reque insolens in vel?</button>
</div>`, а второй над контентом `<div class="accordion__slot"><div class="accordion__panel">
<p class="accordion-panel__content">Quidam vocibus eum ne, erat consectetuer voluptatibus ut nam. Eu usu vidit tractatos, vero tractatos ius an, in mel diceret persecuti.</p></div>
</div>`.

Comment: @azlov благодарю